# Change theme using knockout in asp.net on master page, change theme dynamically

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, themes, master-pages

How can I change the theme dynamically using knockout in asp.net as we can change theme using `app_theme` folder on `page_preinit` method in cs file in `app_code` folder?

I want to change the theme using knockout on the master page.

Comment: ASP.NET Themes are a server-side technology while knockout is client-side (in the browser).  Do you want to know how to do a postback in knockout so you can switch themes on the server?

Comment: Use [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).